# how sign a xml and pdf use a digital signature in php

Tags: php, xml, digital-signature

Someone could give me tips on how to do this in php, i have a .cert file and rsa key and need sign to xml from invoice. Also need sign a pdf file, any ideas?
Thx

Comment: By packages you can do that with built-in features by PHAR files... By other files you have to generate a checksum with sha1_file() and sign it with the private key. After that you can verify it with the public key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707794/how-to-digitally-sign-a-file-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407523/how-to-add-digital-signature-rsa-certificate-etc-to-any-of-file-using-php

Comment: Please use the search first, and use the ask functionality on this website for concrete programming questions only. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no PHP-only way to sign XML and PDFs according to XMLDSig and PDF standards, though you can sign using PKCS#7 with OpenSSL functions.

If you need XMLDSig and PDF signing, your best option is to create an executable for your platform and call it from PHP somehow.

Within our SecureBlackbox product we are working on PHP edition, but it will be a wrapper for a native .dll/.so library, not PHP-only solution. The reason is that it makes no sense to translate the enormous amount of cryptography-related code to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

What about running the signing process in shell?

```
shell_exec("gpg --output signature.sig --sign file")
```

And then provide the `signature.sig` for download.

I don't see what the filetype has to do with it. `gpg` signs files regardless of content/type/...