# PHP creation of signature

Tags: php, security, cryptography

I am thinking of a way to create digital signatures. I need this because some files needed to be signed like certificates by a authorized user and the receiving user must see it is from a authorized and also in case of disputes the issued user must verify it is his file.

For that I am trying to upload an image with actual signature inside the image.

**Question:** Can i get unique values from the signature image?

I am thinking to get unique value from the image and then give to the `openssl_sign` with an encrypted form of unique values from the signature image as the private key.

By this the issuing user can sign and also verify the file it is his. But the receiving user will require a key to open the file.

**Question:** Can i give key to user(a key that is only available to receiving user) to open that encrypted file?

I have searched but had trouble finding these things. Please explain these things and please give a better idea if my logic is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, [**digital signature** is a specific cryptography term](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded#digital-signatures). It's a form of public-key cryptography where you sign a message with your private key, and anyone can verify the signature with your public key.

A digital signature is NOT:

- A cryptographic hash function, such as MD5 (although they utilize hash functions internally)
- A digital equivalent to a traditional pen-and-paper signature

If you need a "digital" equivalent to a pen-and-paper signature for legal reasons, consult a lawyer. Throwing cryptography at a legal problem is *scarcely* a good move, especially since most law professionals don't even know what RSA stands for, let alone how it works.

If it turns out you just want a cryptographic digital signature, [grab libsodium and use `crypto_sign_detached()`](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/05-publickey-crypto.md). It's way more secure what PHP gives you natively (`openssl_sign()` is RSA + SHA1).

Comment: Thnaks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but here are a couple of comments/suggestions:

1. A ["digital signature"](https://www.docusign.com/how-it-works/electronic-signature/digital-signature/digital-signature-faq) is one thing.  An image of a handwritten signature is a completely different thing.
2. If you wish, you *can* associate an image with a digital signature.  This will involve creating a certificate. Here is a good discussion:

[How to add digital signature (RSA, Certificate, etc) to any of file, using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407523/how-to-add-digital-signature-rsa-certificate-etc-to-any-of-file-using-php)

3. You can also use a certificate for ["non-repudiation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation) - to guarantee the person uploading the image is in fact the person who made the image.